# sklearn: Modify weights for parameter of Isolation Forest

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, outliers

I am using IsolationForest (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html) for outlier detection.

Say I have a dataframe with `n` features from `X1`, `X2` to `Xn`.

I would like to define intuitively that `X1` is a more important feature, so if a data point has a value of `X1` differently it might be considered as an outlier more than if this data point has `X3` differently.

How could I do that with Isolation Forest, or by modifying the original data?

Comment: Why do you think its important. If the model finds it important, it would have given it more weight automatically.

Comment: It comes from domain knowledge in fact. For instance, I want to detect ``outlier`` cluster node, and I know that CPU temperature is an important indicator more than  network sending rate at that moment

Comment: Well that's what I am saying. As per your example CPU temperature will not be in the average range in that case. Given that model has seen (or infact not seen) any such samples, the model will take that into while calculating the anamoly score.

Comment: Yes, but I would like to that into score. Consider 2 data points, one with ``strange`` CPU temperature, and one with ``strange`` network rate. I would like to say that the first one should have a higher outlier score than the second one, given other information are the same. For shake of simplicity let's assume the level of ``strangeness`` are the same in two cases: say 10 standard deviations from mean for example.